# macOS Github actions queued, "The agent pool assigned to this job has hit their MacOs concurrency limits", why?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-runners

Our team has (essentially) a CI system built in github actions, which spawns 5 testing jobs for a PR. This requires macOS github-hosted action runners. When more than one PR is being built, our jobs will often end up queued, with the following message:

```
The agent pool assigned to this job has hit their MacOs concurrency limits
```

Because github-hosted action runners are on-demand, this limit is surprising. What is it, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of this writing (27 Apr 2023), the number of concurrent jobs running on github-hosted action runners is limited, based on your organization's GitHub plan, and runner type, like so:

[image: the sad news]

And as usual on GitHub, anything related to macOS gets some sort of special penalty. As "Not applicable" might indicate -- and confirmed by my testing -- the concurrent macOS limit does not bump to 500 when switched to the "larger" [`-xl` version](https://github.blog/2023-03-01-github-actions-introducing-faster-github-hosted-x64-macos-runners/) of the macOS runner. Same old limits apply.

Otherwise, apparently these numbers can be upped only for Enterprise.

> Note: If required, customers on enterprise plans can request a higher limit for concurrent jobs. For more information, contact GitHub Enterprise Support or your sales representative.

This information comes from [github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#usage-limits).

Comment: It's kind of weird how if you have say 6 jobs and the first 5 are completed, the last one just hangs instead of reusing the previous runners.

Edit: huh, nevermind, I was actually running 5 jobs and the 5th hanged with this message. The docs do indeed mention 5 limit, that's weird.